# Symfony 1.4 sfWidgetFormJQueryDate with time

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have form with date field. I am using `sfWidgetFormJQueryDate` for nice calendar widget. But this widget cannot setup time as well as date. I googled for a while and found [solution](http://pookey.co.uk/wordpress/archives/170-datetime-range-selector-widget-for-symfony). But I am using it in admin panel and as last paragraph said I need to override some methods. The really problem is with `doUpdateObject` method. I have always current date and time.

This is my setup part of form:

```
  $minutes = array();
  for($i = 0; $i < 60; ++$i)
  {
      $minutes[$i] = sprintf('%02d', $i);
  }

  $this->widgetSchema['orderDate'] = new sfWidgetFormDateTimeRange(array(
      'from_date' => new sfWidgetFormJQueryDate(),
      'from_time' => new sfWidgetFormTime(array('minutes' => $minutes))
  );
```

and in my `doUpdateObject` method I have:

```
public function doUpdateObject($values){
  print_r($values);
  print_r($this->getValues());
  parent::doUpdateObject($values);
  print_r($values);
  print_r($this->getValues());
  exit;
}
```

Every single print_r never shows data from the widget it always has value of current date and time. How can I achieve this? This project works with Symfony 1.4.

Comment: Why do you use the 'doUpdateObject' instead of 'updateObject'? Did you copy the code which is used in the example you posted? Also - are you using the widget in a filter or in a model's form?

Comment: because `doUpdateObject` is invoked inside `updateObject` and as documentation said this is a right way to do it. Despite of it I have tried with `updateObject` method as well with the same results. This is form, not a filter.

Comment: Did you try to add the part `if (null === $values) { $values = $this->values; }`. It seems that it should help.

Comment: yep I tried, but this part is in `updateObject` method itself. This check is rather redundant here. `doUpdateObject` is invoked from inside of `updateObject` just below this check.

Comment: despite it I said that $values are the same, but not null, those lines do nothing for me.

Comment: Hmm... I just noticed that you use `$this->getValues()` but the function updates the object. So if you run `$this->getObject()` before and after the `doUpdateObject` it should return the object with the updated values.

Comment: No it didn't help at all, but the problem was in... validator. Somehow date in form didn't pass validation so date widget adjust date and time to actual data. After I fixed validation problem everything started to work just fine.